# Получить статус запроса ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

Получаю ответ от API OpenWeatherMap. Каким образом можно было бы получить код ответа и в зависимости от него отобразить контент? К примеру, если статус `404` то вывести `...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой и примитивный пример. Добавим в конструкторе в `state` несколько параметров:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    loading: true, // режим загрузки
    statusCode: null, // статус ответа
  }
}
```

Конструктор может содержать и другой код, но для примера мы определили две переменные в стейте, `loading` - режим загрузки, как только мы попадаем в конструктор, проставляем сюда `true`, как только мы получим ответ от API - поменяем этот параметр, и, соответственно и `statusCode` поменяем - запишем туда код ответа. Далее, к примеру внутри метода `componentDidMount`  делаем отправку запроса:

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch... // тут ваш API запрос
     .then((response) => {
       this.setState({ loading: false, statusCode: response.status });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
       this.setState({ loading: false });
     });
}
```

А внутри рендеринга добавим простые проверки на статус и загрузку из `state`:

```
render() {
  // ответ пока не получен - загрузка
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return (<p>Loading...</p>);
  }

  // ответ получен, но нет статуса ответа (смотри консоль)
  if (!this.state.loading && !this.state.statusCode) {
    return (<p>Something went wrong. See console logging.</p>);
  }

  // ответ получен, статус 200
  if (this.state.statusCode === 200) {
    return (<p>All good</p>);
  }

  // ответ получен, статус 404    
  if (this.state.statusCode === 404) {
    return (<p>Not found</p>);
  }

  // ответ получен, остальные статусы
  return (<p>Unexpected status code: {this.state.statusCode}</p>);
}
```

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

- [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)
- [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
- [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/error)